# Concatenar dos campos

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy concatenando dos campos pero me esta mostrando pegado el final de un capo con el otro. ejemplo: Pedro PabloCastro Ruíz

```html
SELECT documento, concat(nombres, '', apellidos) as datos, nacimiento FROM jugador
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El error está en las comillas debe de dar un espacio

```html
SELECT documento, concat(nombres, ' ', apellidos) as datos, nacimiento FROM jugador
```

> El `CONCAT` lo que hace es concatenar dos o más columnas de una tabla,
>   es decir visualizar los datos de 2 o más columnas en una sola, como en
>   el caso suyo tiene la columna **`Nombre`** Y **`Apellido`** y el `CONCAT` te
>   permite visualizar ambos en un solo campo, puedes agregar palabras en
>   los campos a concatenar o espacios en blanco como es tu caso.

Comment: @JackNavaRow barbaro! :'D

Comment: una pregunta, es posible insertar el dia(dato_numerico),año(dato_numerico);semana(dato_numerico) e insertarlos en una sola tabla, o habra algun otro modo, es decri: quiero tener el año-numerodesemana-numerodeldia en un solo campo, por ejemplo 195103  donde 19=año 51=semana 03=dia . año=2019  semana=51 del año y di= 03 de esa semana.

Answer (score 6):

Es preciso tener presente que **[`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** tiene **un serio problema con los valores `NULL`**:

> `CONCAT()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.
>
> ---
>
> `CONCAT()` devuelve `NULL` si cualquier argumento es `NULL`.

Por lo tanto, en MySQL **debes** usar **[`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)** si entre los valores que vas a concatenar puede haber valores `NULL`.

> `CONCAT_WS()` does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any
>   `NULL` values after the separator argument.

Además, en caso de que tengas que concatenar varias columnas y el separador sea siempre el mismo, el código queda más limpio.

Por ejemplo:

Si usando `CONCAT` tienes que escribir esto:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(col1, ' ', col2, ' ', col3, ' ', col4, ' ', col5, ... col999-y-999separadores) 
as datos;
```

Con `CONCAT_WS` pones el separador **sólo una vez**, al principio, y listo:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS(' ', col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, ... col999) 
as  datos;
```

---

#### Es importante prestar atención a esto

Veamos [una demo](http://rextester.com/ZOCVS8524) de lo que ocurre si hubiese nulos entre los valores que quieres concatenar. 
**Con `CONCAT` nunca vas a ver a Santiago porque su apellido es `NULL` !!! :)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persona (
    id         SERIAL,
    nombre     VARCHAR(50),
    apellido   VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Pedro','Pérez');
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Santiago',NULL);
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Juan',' ');

-- Tratamiento de NULL con CONCAT_WS
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',nombre, apellido) datos FROM persona;

-- Tratamiento de NULL con CONCAT ... ¡terrible!
SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ',apellido) datos FROM persona;
```

**`Resultado con CONCAT_WS:`**

```
    datos
1   Pedro Pérez
2   Santiago
3   Juan
```

**`Resultado ¡terrible! con CONCAT:`**

```
    datos
1   Pedro Pérez
2   NULL
3   Juan
```

---

> PD: Para más detalles se puede consultar esta pregunta:
>
> - [¿Usar CONCAT o CONCAT_WS en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967)

Comment: No entiendo lo del NULL, pues si crea la tabla y un campo es NULL, simplemente cuando se hace el registro no guardaría nada en ese campo y al hacer el CONCAT traería el dato del primer campo y el segundo vació por así decirlo, pues a mi me trae  el nombre cuando el campo apellido es null

Comment: No @Scorpion Si tiene el valor `NULL`, no concatena **nada**, como dice la documentación y como muestra el ejemplo al final, en el registro número 2 (`Santiago`). Otra cosa es que sea **una cadena vacía, que no es lo mismo que `NULL`**, fíjate que en el insert del registro 3 (`Juan`) se inserta una cadena vacía y no hay problema.

Comment: Si en eso estamos de acuerdo, lo que digo es que no veo la necesidad de insertar en un campo la "palabra" NULL o al menos no lo he necesitado.

Comment: @Scorpion La inserción de `NULL` en el ejemplo es intencional, para mostrar lo que ocurre. No es algo descabellado, sino que reproduce situaciones reales, ya que  **en cualquier BD puedes tener campos que admiten `NULL` y ese será su valor si no insertas nada en ellos**. En cualquiera de esos casos el `CONCAT` actuará como ha ocurrido con el registro número 2.

Comment: @ A. Cedano comprendo y aprecio su punto de vista.

Answer (score 1):

No estás colocando el espacio, simplemente una cadena sin texto, debes intentarlo así:

```
SELECT documento, concat(nombres, ' ', apellidos) as datos, nacimiento FROM jugador
                                   ^ Aquí
```

o incluso así:

```
SELECT documento, datos = nombres + ' ' + apellidos, nacimiento FROM jugador
```

`CONCAT` simplemente une textos, uno tras otro, de los que pases como parámetros separados por comas (`,`), puedes unir en un solo texto todos los que quieras; para el caso antes de unir los dos `VARCHAR` que quieres debes agregar, entre ambos, el espacio en blanco que es lo que le faltó a tu consulta original.

El segundo caso que te puse hace prácticamente lo mismo, *concatenar* pero "agregando" el texto a la derecha del `+` al texto que está a la izquierda siendo *técnicamente* distinto a `CONCAT` que crea un nuevo texto pero finalmente obtiene el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en las etiquetas indicas que es para MySql, por si alguien llega a esta pregunta interesado por otros lenguajes, en otros lenguajes (que recuerde ahora mismo por ejemplo PostgreSQL o Multibase) la contatenación se realiza con `||`.

Tu ejemplo resultaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT documento, nombres || ' ' || apellidos as datos, nacimiento FROM jugador
```