# ¿Usar CONCAT o CONCAT_WS en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string

Como ya sabemos, MySQL cuenta con dos funciones para concatenar cadenas: `CONCAT` y `CONCAT_WS`.

Respondiendo a una pregunta, vi que `CONCAT` no arroja los resultados esperados cuando al menos uno de los valores es igual a `NULL`.

**¿Cuándo se recomienda entonces usar `CONCAT` y cuándo usar `CONCAT_WS`?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### I. Lo que dice la documentación

Veamos primero lo que explica la documentación sobre ambas funciones:

#### [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

> `CONCAT()` devuelve `NULL` si cualquiera de sus argumentos es `NULL`.

Dicho de otro modo, cualquier valor `NULL` que entre en un `CONCAT` anula a los demás valores.

#### [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

> `CONCAT_WS()` no omite cadenas vacías. Sin embargo, omite cualquier
>   valor `NULL` después del argumento del separador.

---

### II. Determinando cuál usar en un escenario real

Supongamos un diseño de tabla como este:

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS persona 
    (
      persona_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      nombre              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      apellido_paterno    VARCHAR(50),
      apellido_materno    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );
```

#### (a) El problema de `CONCAT` con los valores `NULL`

El diseño de tabla mostrado más arriba es un diseño común, de hecho, cualquier tabla podría tener columnas como **`apellido_paterno`**, es decir, columnas que admitan valores `NULL`. Y no solo eso, en cualquier inserción que no asigne valores a esas columnas, su valor por defecto será `NULL`.

Eso significa que, si hacemos una inserción parecida a esta:

```
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido_materno) 
            VALUES  ('Pedro','Pérez');
```

la columna `apellido_paterno` recibirá por defecto el valor `NULL`.

Si nosotros usamos `CONCAT` en nuestra tabla `persona`:

```
-- Tratamiento de NULL con CONCAT ... ¡terrible!

SELECT CONCAT(
              apellido_paterno, ' ', apellido_materno, ', ', nombre
             ) datos FROM persona;
```

El resultado, en el caso de `Pedro Pérez` será:

```
    datos
1   NULL
```

O sea, ni Pedro, ni Pérez, ni nada... solamente `NULL`. Verdaderamente terrible ¿no?

Nótese que `NULL` y una **cadena vacía** no son lo mismo. Probemos otro `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno) 
            VALUES  ('Juan', '', 'Arias');
```

Como eres observador, has visto que la columna `apellido_paterno` está recibiendo una cadena vacía `''`.

Y veremos que `CONCAT()` es amigo de las cadenas vacías... Es que `CONCAT()` tiene sus preferencias... no es justo, ¡no! :)

El resultado del `SELECT` anterior para `Juan Arias` será:

```
    datos
3    Arias, Juan
```

El problema es que cuando no se indica ningún valor explícitamente, la columna adquiere un valor `NULL` y eso es terrible si usamos `CONCAT`.

---

#### (b) El comportamiento de `CONCAT_WS()`

Veamos qué tal se comporta `CONCAT_WS()` con nuestro amigo `Pedro Pérez`:

```
-- Tratamiento de NULL con CONCAT_WS ... ¡genial +!

SELECT CONCAT_WS(
                  ' ', apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, nombre
                ) datos 
        FROM persona;
```

Daría como resultado:

```
    datos
1   Pérez Pedro
```

¿Y con `Juan Arias`?:

```
    datos
3    Arias Juan
```

¡Este `CONCAT_WS` entonces es *casi* una maravilla!

Según su sintaxis, hay que poner el separador al principio solamente, y luego la lista de columnas o valores que queremos concatenar. Si el separador es el mismo es maravilloso, pero **¿y si necesito diferentes separadores?**.

**¡Podemos hacerlo!**, poniendo una cadena vacía como separador y concatenando las columnas y valores como hacemos con `CONCAT()`, o sea, *handmade*:

```
-- Tratamiento de NULL con CONCAT_WS y varios separadores ... ¡genial ++!

SELECT CONCAT_WS(
                  '', apellido_paterno, ' ', apellido_materno, ', ' ,nombre
                ) datos 
        FROM persona;
```

El resultado sería:

```
    datos
1    Pérez, Pedro
2   Ruiz García, Santiago
3    Arias, Juan
```

Bueno, pero... ¡hay un espacio en blanco cuando falta algún dato! Eso tiene solución, te toca a ti buscarla.

---

### III. Conclusión

Visto que `CONCAT()`:

- No es amigo de los valores `NULL`
- Nos obliga a repetir el separador aún en los casos en que el separador no cambia

Y visto que `CONCAT_WS()`:

- Es amigo de los valores `NULL`
- Puede ser usado como si fuese `CONCAT()` en los casos en que el separador cambia

Podemos concluir que **se puede usar `CONCAT_WS()` en todos los casos** y si se quiere usar `CONCAT()` debemos estar **totalmente seguros** de que todos los valores que intervienen **ninguno** es `NULL`.

---

Una demo completa del código usado en la respuesta [se puede encontrar aquí](http://rextester.com/CROR93931).

Comment: el concat se usaria mas para crear un registro y validarlo dentro de un select esa es su ventaja y por que no esta deprecado

Comment: @JackNavaRow ¿crear un registro y validarlo? no entendí. Y lo de _deprecado_ tampoco. ¿Podrías explicarme? Gracias.

Comment: si consultaras dos tablas y debes concatenar y por alguna razon debes validar ese concatenacion con el concat_ws no lo podrias hacer, tendrias que hacer un if al campo que sabes que puede ser null y luego el concat_ws, lo cual seria menos optimo; espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: @A. Cedano. Una pregunta muy interesante y la respuesta también. Personalmente prefiero usar el `CONCAT` y cuando tengo que tratar con posibles resultados `nulos` utilizo el `IFNULL` que me permite convertir un valor nulo en cualquier otro valor que indique en el parámetro de la función.