# ¿Cómo separar por una coma "," una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, he tenido problemas en separar un consulta, verán este es mi código, de la base de datos extraigo las alarmas así se llama el campo, hay solo 3 opciones "Alarma", "Aviso" y "Ambas" solo se pueda insertar una en un registro cuando extraigo la consulta lo muestra así;

> AlarmaAviso

Y yo quiero que lo muestre asi;

> Alarma,Aviso

(con la coma) ya intente con `implode`, pero no logre hacerlo bien, me salia así;

> AlarmaAviso,AlarmaAviso.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM notificaciones
WHERE idDepto = " .$_POST['id_depto']."";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{// Datos obtenidos de la consulta
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{

$noti  = $row["Notificacion"];  //Nombre de notificacion Alarma/ Aviso / Ambas
$verialarma = $noti;
echo    $verialarma;

 } else {

echo "0 resultados"; //Validacion

        }

     $conn->close();
```

Comment: `hay solo 3 "Alarma", "Aviso" y "Ambas"` = ¿hay solo 3, qué, registros en la tabla `Notificaciones`? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta con el contenido de la tabla `Notificaciones` = el resultado de ejecutar el SELECT que tienes en tu código.

Comment: ¿`CONCAT_WS` no te sirve? Sugiero que **[veas esta pregunta y su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967)**. Otra opción sería `GROUP_CONCAT`... pero como no das más detalles del contexto, estás teniendo varios tipos de respuestas para hacer algo que quizá podría ser más simple de lo que se cree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que se podria implementar es una concatenación de una "," a cada elemento que te trae la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$verialarma = "";
$contador = 1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{// Datos obtenidos de la consulta
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $noti  = $row["Notificacion"];  //Nombre de notificacion Alarma/ Aviso / Ambas
    if($result->num_rows != $contador){
        $verialarma = $noti.",";
    }else{
        $verialarma = $verialarma.$noti;
    }
    $contador++;

}
echo    $verialarma;
```

Podrias hacer la prueba y decirme si te funciona es que no pude hacer la prueba ya que no tengo instalado PHP en mi maquina. Cualquier duda lo podriamos checar.

Comment: Gracias voy a probar, no lo habia planteado de esa manera, comento los resultados en cuanto lo realice.

Comment: Me funciono muy bien de esta manera, los separa de esta forma Alarma,Aviso antes habia intentado asi: echo $vars = $verialarma.','; concatene la coma al final de la vaiable 'verialarma' y eso lo puse dentro de $vars, aunque funciona bien, me lo imprimia asi Alarma,Aviso, agregando una coma al final al imprimir. gracias.

Comment: Para eso esta la comunidad para apoyarse, Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

No veo tu código completo, como **¿Donde termina el while?** y No sé si **$noti** te esté retornando el array que estas buscando

Pero asumiendo que ya obtienes como resultado: **AlarmaAviso**, esto indica que estas usando implode sin un caracter para unir los elementos en tu caso la coma (",")

Sintaxis: **implode ( string $glue, array $array );** obtenida del [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

Al final solo unes tu cadena de la sigiente manera:

```
$verialarma = implode ("," , $noti);
```

Comment: Disculpa, si el codigo estaba incompleto, ya lo modifique, e intente con tu ejemplo pero me aparece de esta manera, AlarmaAviso,AlarmaAviso

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que entiendo lo que necesitas es que cuando ya has recuperado `AlarmaAviso` te lo ponga de este modo `Alarma,Aviso`.

Para ello, puedes utilizar la función **[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)** de PHP. Con ella, y mediante una regex, puedes detectar las letras mayúsculas e insertar una coma delante de ellas. Posteriormente, podrás utilizar la función **[`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ltrim.php)** para eliminar la coma que se ha insertado delante de la primera palabra de la cadena.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $cadena = 'AlarmaAviso';
    $cadenaReemplazada = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', ',$0', $cadena);
    $cadenaReemplazada = ltrim($cadenaReemplazada, ',');

    echo $cadenaReemplazada; //Devuelve Alarma,Aviso
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa21aecbffbd7026aaa502f49dbf721a670b3a03)**.

Comment: Gracias voy a intenar, comento los resultados en cuanto lo realice.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo podrías obtener usando `GROUP_CONCAT`.

No explicas bien el contexto. Pero si en el departamento 1 ocurren las notificaciones  `Alarma` y `Aviso` y las mismas existen en filas diferentes de una tabla, `GROUP_CONCAT` te permite obtener una sola fila de resultados con todas las notificaciones ocurridas según los criterios aplicados a la consulta.

Es decir, si en la consulta tu colocas un `WHERE dpto_id=1` y luego aplicas un `GROUP BY dpto_id` lo que hará `GROUP_CONCAT` es devolverte una sola fila separada por el separador que tú indiques agrupados por cada departamento. Claro está, se pueden agregar más criterios, tanto en el `WHERE` como en el `GROUP BY`.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/edit/VRSRN77589)

```
 CREATE TABLE notificaciones (
          notificacion_id  SERIAL,
          notificacion VARCHAR(50),
          dpto_id INT
        );

 INSERT INTO notificaciones (notificacion, dpto_id) 
             VALUES 
             ('Alarma',1),
             ('Aviso',1),
             ('Ambas',2),
             ('Alarma',3),
             ('Aviso',3)
  ; 

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(notificacion SEPARATOR ",") notificaciones
FROM notificaciones WHERE dpto_id=1 GROUP BY dpto_id;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
    notificaciones
1   Alarma,Aviso
```

---

**Nota de seguridad:**
El código usado en tu pregunta es vulnerable a la inyección SQL. Se recomienda usar consultas preparadas, ejemplo:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(notificacion SEPARATOR ",") notificaciones
FROM notificaciones WHERE dpto_id=? GROUP BY dpto_id;
```

Pasando aparte el valor del campo `dpto_id`, para evitar de ese modo la [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967).

Comment: Valla, muchas gracias, tratare de buscar mas por la seguridad, ese lo tome de un ejemplo y lo adapte a mi proyecto, lo cambiare a consulta preparada mejor.