# Consulta SQL con dos campos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el problema en una consulta SQL ya que en un campo con auto complete me regresa el nombre completo de la persona que busco en este caso son nombre y apellido, eso lo manda por post a un archivo php que genera la tabla a partir de la consulta SQL sin embargo no encuentra a nadie por que por obvias razones al buscar por el campo nombre no hay nadie llamado así ya que el parámetro recibido es la consulta de nombre y apellido

**Esta es mi consulta sql en PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT Nombre,Apellidos, ct_asistencias_loc.fecha, hora, ct_asistencias_loc.Status from ct_alumnos INNER JOIN ct_asistencias_loc on ct_alumnos.idAlumno=ct_asistencias_loc.idAlumno where Nombre ='".$_POST['nombre']."'";
```

Un ejemplo del parametro recibido para la consulta es el nombre de "*Ramon Guillermo Juarez Carbajal*"

En mi base de datos tengo los campos de nombre y apellido, mi pregunta es como hacer la consulta para que use el where desde las dos tablas o que mezcle los datos de nombre y apellido y funcione el LIKE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera se la consulta pregunta tanto en el campo de nombre como en el de apellidos lo que viene por `$_POST` utilizando `LIKE`

```
$sql = "SELECT Nombre,Apellidos, ct_asistencias_loc.fecha, hora, ct_asistencias_loc.Status 
    FROM ct_alumnos 
    INNER JOIN ct_asistencias_loc on ct_alumnos.idAlumno=ct_asistencias_loc.idAlumno 
    WHERE Nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['nombre']."%' OR Apellidos LIKE '%" . $_POST['nombre'] . "'%";
```

Puede ajustar la consulta y en ves de utilizar el `OR` utilizar `AND`, todo depende de como quiere el resultado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes concatenar y comparar los valores concatenados.

Para concatenar puedes usar `CONCAT_WS`:

- Nombre y Apellido exacto, sin `LIKE`:

  ```
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];

  $sql="SELECT 
          Nombre, Apellidos, ct_asistencias_loc.fecha, 
          hora, ct_asistencias_loc.Status, 
          CONCAT_WS(' ', Nombre, Apellidos) nombre_completo 
          FROM ct_alumnos 
          INNER JOIN ct_asistencias_loc on ct_alumnos.idAlumno=ct_asistencias_loc.idAlumno 
          HAVING nombre_completo='".$nombre."'";
  ```
- Nombre y Apellido con `LIKE`:

  ```
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];

  $sql="SELECT 
          Nombre, Apellidos, ct_asistencias_loc.fecha, 
          hora, ct_asistencias_loc.Status, 
          CONCAT_WS(' ', Nombre, Apellidos) nombre_completo 
          FROM ct_alumnos 
          INNER JOIN ct_asistencias_loc on ct_alumnos.idAlumno=ct_asistencias_loc.idAlumno 
          HAVING nombre_completo LIKE '%".$nombre."'%";
  ```

---

O bien `CONCAT`:

- Nombre y apellido exacto, sin `LIKE`:

  ```
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];

  $sql="SELECT 
          Nombre, Apellidos, ct_asistencias_loc.fecha, 
          hora, ct_asistencias_loc.Status, 
          CONCAT(Nombre, ' ', Apellidos) nombre_completo 
          FROM ct_alumnos 
          INNER JOIN ct_asistencias_loc on ct_alumnos.idAlumno=ct_asistencias_loc.idAlumno 
          HAVING nombre_completo='".$nombre."'";
  ```
- Nombre y Apellido con `LIKE`:

  ```
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];

  $sql="SELECT 
          Nombre, Apellidos, ct_asistencias_loc.fecha, 
          hora, ct_asistencias_loc.Status, 
          CONCAT(Nombre, ' ', Apellidos) nombre_completo 
          FROM ct_alumnos 
          INNER JOIN ct_asistencias_loc on ct_alumnos.idAlumno=ct_asistencias_loc.idAlumno 
          HAVING nombre_completo LIKE '%".$nombre."'%";
  ```

---

**Notas:**

- Sobre las consecuencias de usar uno u otro consulta esta pregunta: [¿Usar CONCAT o CONCAT_WS en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967)
- Es posible que necesites usar consultas preparadas para proteger tu código de la Inyección SQL
- Cuando intervienen dos tablas, es conveniente poner en cada columna el nombre de la tabla delante, para evitar posibles nombres de columnas ambiguas, en cuyo caso el código fallará.