# Cómo concatenar dos campos de una tabla en pares en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Poseo la siguiente tabla

```
Compras
Id_compra
Total
```

Datos de ejemplo

```
1 50900
2 69999
3 55909
```

Quisiera obtener lo siguiente al concatenar

```
1-50900,
2-69999,
3-55909
```

Utilice

```
concat(id_compra, total separator "-")
```

Pero me está generando primero todos los ids y luego los totales

Cómo puedo concatenar y obtener los pares ID y total separados por guiones.???

Comment: Quiero decirte dos cosas: 1º. Para este caso concreto, **evita el uso de `CONCAT`** (**[mira aquí por qué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967)**); 2º. Lo puedes hacer con `CONCAT_WS`  de este modo: `SELECT CONCAT_WS('',id_compra,'-',total,',') datos FROM ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay casos en los que **conviene evitar el uso de `CONCAT`**, y creo que éste es uno de ellos.

Te podrás sorprender de lo dicho anteriormente. [Aquí he explicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967) con prueba de código, por qué no siempre es bueno el uso de `CONCAT` y por qué en esos casos hay una mejor alternativa.

Tu consulta se podría resolver *sin riesgo* usando `CONCAT_WS`, del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS('',id_compra,'-',total,',') datos 
FROM ...
```

Me pareció entender que querías una coma `,` al final de tus resultados, por eso `total,','` ...

Answer (score 1):

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
SELECT CONCAT(id_compra, '-', total) AS 'concat'
    FROM compras
```

Donde el resultado seria el siguiente:

```
| concat
---------
|1-50900
---------
|2-69999
---------
|3-55909
```