# ¿Cómo muestro unos parámetros u otros en un sql dependiendo de un if?

Tags: mysql

Quiero recoger dos campos si tengo un valor en una columna u otros si tengo otro valor en la misma columna pero al hacerlo con esta consulta:

```
SELECT
CASE portada.id 
WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT name, comment FROM portada)
WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT route FROM portada)
ELSE 0 
END 
FROM portada;
```

siempre obtengo el mismo resultado...

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

¿alguien sabría si es factible hacer esta consulta en mysql o no queda más remedio que hacerlo mediante un if de código en la aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene porque tu subquery está devolviendo 2 columnas pero "proyectando" el resultado sobre una columna.

No sé si simplemente quieres obtener el valor de `name` y `comment` o los quieres utilizar para otro `JOIN` más adelante. En el primer caso una opción que tienes es concatenar el `name` y el `comment`

```
SELECT
CASE id 
WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT(name,' ', comment)
WHEN 3 THEN route
ELSE 0 
END 
FROM portada;
```

[Aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/680bcd) el ejemplo

Comment: El [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/680bcd) que has indicado no tiene consulta de prueba...

Comment: mmm, creo que no se guardan las consultas... en todo caso es la que he puesto en la respuesta :)

Comment: Ok. Aunque quiero señalar que **se debe tener cuidado con `CONCAT`**. Prueba a insertar una fila así: `INSERT INTO portada VALUES(2, 'nombre 1', null, 'Route 1');` y verás el *terrible* comportamiento de `CONCAT` cuando hay valores nulos. [En esta pregunta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967) he tratado con amplitud ese comportamiento no deseado y la forma de prevenirlo.