# Como hacer una consulta con datos no relacionados MySQL

Tags: mysql

¿Como puedo hacer esta consulta en mysql?

```
`SELECT * FROM tblEmpleados e LEFT JOIN tblUsuarios u on u.usuarios_nombres,' 'u.usuarios_apellido_paterno  LIKE` concat('%',e.empleados_nombres,'%','%',e.empleados_apellido_paterno,'%')
```

No tengo un campo `ID` que los relacione, se me ocurrió hacer un `left join` con un `like` por los nombres

```
tabla empleados
----------------
nombre
juanito elbrayan

tabla usuarios
----------------
nombreUsuario
juanito elbrayan
```

pero me sale `NULL` en los campos de la derecha.

Comment: Hola, por favor mejora la calidad de la pregunta, no eres nuevo, te van a votar negativo y para concatenar en mysql lo puedes hacer así `concat('%',e.empleados_nombres,'%')` con comas

Comment: puedo añadir otro campo por ejemplo apellidos?

Comment: `concat()` puede tener la cantidad de campos que tu quieras separados por comas

Comment: Tienes que escribir la consulta así: `SELECT * FROM tblUsuarios u LEFT JOIN tblEmpleados e on u.usuarios_nombres = LIKE concat('%',e.empleados_nombres,'%')` ... revisa la sintaxis de `CONCAT`. Al usar el signo de `+` lo que haces sumarle la cadena `%` a la columna, dándote como resultado `0`  en cada columna. Aunque lo extraño es que no tengas una columna `ID` para las relaciones. Si dejas las tablas así, podrían ralentizarse en un futuro, cuando la BD crezca.

Comment: mira la edito en mi pregunta

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblEmpleados e LEFT JOIN tblUsuarios u on u.usuarios_nombres,' 'u.usuarios_apellido_paterno  LIKE concat('%',e.empleados_nombres,'%','%',e.empleados_apellido_paterno,'%')

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil, llámame si aun no te sale, saludos.

Comment: ya me salio con los concat pero me aparece muchosresultados por que hay varios con el mismo nombre

Comment: se puede agregar apellido paterno en el concat? por ejemplo  SELECT * FROM tblEmpleados e LEFT JOIN tblUsuarios u on u.usuarios_nombres,' 'u.usuarios_apellido_paterno LIKE concat('%',e.empleados_nombres,'%','%',e.empleados_apellido_paterno,'%')

Comment: ya me salio muchas gracias

Comment: Y ten cuidado cuando uses `CONCAT`, ya que esta función no es *NULL safe*, significa que si entre varias columnas una sola es `NULL`, hará que el valor de la concatenación sea `NULL`. [Puedes ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967) para más detalles y para una alternativa.

Comment: lo voy a verel dia de mañana con calma por ahora lo cambie por un INNER JOIN y me salio bien, pero si voy a leer la recomendacion que me mandaste muchas gracias.

Comment: Tenes suficiente reputacion como para saber que la respuesta no va en el cuerpo de la pregunta!

Answer (score 1):

Aqui dejo la respuesta no se enojen

```
SELECT concat(u.usuarios_nombres,' ',u.usuarios_apellido_paterno,' ',u.usuarios_apellido_materno) 
AS nombre,u.usuarios_usuario,e.empleados_puesto,e.departamento 
FROM tblEmpleados e 
INNER JOIN tblUsuarios u ON concat(u.usuarios_nombres,' ',u.usuarios_apellido_paterno,' ',u.usuarios_apellido_materno) 
LIKE concat('%',e.empleados_nombres,'%','%',e.empleados_apellido_paterno,'%','%',e.empleados_apellido_materno,'%')
```

gracias por su ayuda