# ¿Se puede colocar un cero en una consulta si no existe igualdad al comparar dos campos en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas en una base de datos (en Mysql) ambas tablas tienen diferentes campos, de la cual una tiene un campo llamado `cuenta` y `costo`, y la otra un campo llamado `numero`:

```
Tabla uno
cuenta      |   costo
```

Y,

```
Tabla dos
numero
```

De la tabla dos debo realizar una concatenación para obtener un campo llamado `referencia`

```
select concat('1','-45',numero,'-12')referencia from dos
```

Comparo el campo `cuenta` y `referencia` de cada una de las tablas y si los campos son iguales entonces imprimir el campo `costo`.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
select u.costo
from dos d LEFT JOIN uno u ON concat('1','-45',d.numero,'-12')=u.cuenta
```

Por lo que en mi consulta debería mostrarme 3 columnas; los campos concatenados, el campo numero y por ultimo la consulta que muestre de la igualdad y lo que quiero es que me queden los campos vacíos o con 0 en aquellos campos donde no hayan igualdades.

Comment: Prueba así: **`select u.costo, concat('1','-45',d.numero,'-12') referencia, COALESCE(u.cuenta,'0') cuenta
from dos d LEFT JOIN uno u ON concat('1','-45',d.numero,'-12')=u.cuenta`** Si no pones las columnas en la parte del `SELECT` no te mostrará los datos de las mismas. Y para cambiar el valor de `cuenta` por un `0`  cuando haya nulos puedes usar `COALESCE`.

Comment: gracias si me sirvio mucho la consulta, y la deje usando concat ya que realice varias pruebas y si me proporciona los datos correctos

Comment: Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todas las columnas que necesitas en el resultado final de la consulta deben ser puestas en el `SELECT`.

Y, para cambiar el valor de `NULL` por un `0` cuando no haya coincidencias en el `LEFT JOIN` puedes usar `COALESCE`.

Entonces, puedes escribir tu consulta así:

```
SELECT
    u.costo, 
    CONCAT('1','-45',d.numero,'-12') referencia, 
    COALESCE(u.cuenta,'0') cuenta 
FROM dos d 
LEFT JOIN uno u ON CONCAT('1','-45',d.numero,'-12')=u.cuenta;
```

> **NOTA:** No uses `CONCAT` si existe la posibilidad de que en algunos casos alguna de las columnas que participan en la concatenación puede
>   ser `NULL` ya que en esos casos `CONCAT` establece todo a `NULL`. Si
>   quieres más detalles sobre esto puedes consulta la pregunta:
>   [¿Usar CONCAT o CONCAT_WS en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967) y su respuesta.