# Buscar nombre y apellidos al mismo tiempo en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cuento con un buscador en PHP el cual puede buscar bien el nombre y los apellidos de participantes en una charla independientemente de si se introducen las palabras en mayúsculas o minúsculas o bien si se ponen con acentos o no.
La cuestión es la siguiente:

Puedo buscar a cualquier participante por nombre o apellidos, es decir, si pongo "Pepe" o "Pérez" por ejemplo el resultado que acaba saliendo es "Pepe Pérez", pero si en el buscador pongo el nombre y apellido, o sea "Pepe Pérez" no salen resultados. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de arreglarlo que no sea añadiendo otro campo en el formulario y poniendo en la consulta con LIKE el otro campo donde los apellidos. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios 
         WHERE nombre LIKE _utf8  '%buscar%' 
         OR apellidos LIKE _utf8  '%$buscar%' 
         AND idusuario IN (SELECT idusuario 
         FROM registro_conferencias WHERE idcharla='$id')ORDER BY nombre";
```

El id lo toma de la url y el valor de $buscar se corresponde con lo que el usuario escribe en el formulario de búsqueda, el cual cuenta con un campo de tipo search y un botón de tipo submit.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres buscar tanto por el nombre como por el apellido usando un dato escrito en una sola cadena, puedes usar `LIKE` concatenando.

Por ejemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
         FROM usuarios 
         WHERE 
            CONCAT_WS(' ', nombre, apellidos ) LIKE  '%$buscar%' 
            AND idusuario IN (SELECT idusuario 
         FROM registro_conferencias WHERE idcharla='$id' 
         ORDER BY nombre";
```

Si por ejemplo quieres dar cobertura a búsquedas como `Pepe Pérez` (nombre y apellido) o `Pérez Pepe` (apellido y nombre), puedes poner un `OR` moviendo las columnas de orden:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
         FROM usuarios 
         WHERE 
            CONCAT_WS(' ', nombre,    apellidos) LIKE  '%$buscar%' OR
            CONCAT_WS(' ', apellidos, nombre   ) LIKE  '%$buscar%' 
            AND idusuario IN (SELECT idusuario 
         FROM registro_conferencias WHERE idcharla='$id' 
         ORDER BY nombre";
```

Así encontrará el dato, tanto si escribe `Pepe Pérez` como si escribe `Pérez Pepe`.

---

#### Algunas consideraciones

- Si alguno se extraña de por qué uso `CONCAT_WS` y no `CONCAT`, tiene la respuesta en esta pregunta: [¿Usar CONCAT o CONCAT_WS en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967)
- Tu consulta supone un **grave riesgo de seguridad**. Hay que evitar a toda costa mandar a ejecución consultas con datos dinámicos. Un usuario mal intencionado puede manipular `$buscar` y/o `$id`, para construir un código dañino a niveles muy graves. Cuando sea posible lee sobre *Inyección SQL*. En tu caso deberías usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Y por informarme también sobre la inyección de código. Voy a consultar información sobre ello.

Answer (score 2):

Cambia el primer OR por un AND. Avisame

Estás seleccionando usuarios solamente si se encuentra el nombre Ó apellido. En este caso solamente se seleccionan si se encuentra con nombre Y apellido.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios 
         WHERE nombre LIKE _utf8  '%buscar%' 
         AND apellidos LIKE _utf8  '%$buscar%' 
         AND idusuario IN (SELECT idusuario 
         FROM registro_conferencias WHERE idcharla='$id')ORDER BY nombre";
```

Comment: Estás seleccionando usuarios solamente si se encuentra el nombre Ó apellido. En este caso solamente se seleccionan si se encuentra con nombre Y apellido.

Comment: Usa prepared statemnts, asi como está permite inyectar sql. Y así como está solo traerá un resultado si el nombre contiene el literal 'buscar'.