# concatenar campos en tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esta tabla con esta columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta otra columna en la misma tabla

[image: campos en]

necesito concatenar ambos valores en una sola separado por un espacio en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este codigo pero me da error:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set nombre = 'nombre' . 'referencia'");
```

Comment: Revisa la función `CONCAT()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat Tambien tienes alguna pregunta que aborda esto mismo en el sitio, por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86721/usar-concat-o-concat-ws-en-mysql

Comment: Es raro que quieras combinar valores y guardarlos en una sola columna. ¿Acaso eso no es contrario en cierto modo al concepto de base de datos relacional? ¿Acaso no estarás cayendo en el grave error de redundancia de datos o datos duplicados porque se repiten en varias tablas?

Comment: No importa que se repitan se lo que me hablas de redundancia pero es para generar listas que van a hacer su vida en otro programa

Comment: @A.Cedano Totalmente de acuerdo con lo que indicas. Donde van hacer vida realmente los datos es en la tabla donde los estas duplicando y haciendola crecer de peso inecesariamente.

Comment: Iván esto no justifica que haya redundancia de datos: *pero es para generar listas que van a hacer su vida en otro programa*. ¿Por qué mejor no usar las tablas como tal, haciendo un `JOIN` sobre ellas? ¿Qué pasa si alguno de los datos cambia? ¿Qué pasa si en un futuro hay que agregar un tercer o cuarto o `N` elemento de otra(s) tabla(s)?, etc, etc, etc. No es sólo un problema de redundancia de datos, que es grave, sino que el mantenimiento y garantizar la consistencia de los datos podrían ser muy complicados. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set nombre = concat(nombre,' ',referencia)";
```

La consulta generada en MySQL, es:

```
update NombreTABLA set nombre = concat(nombre,' ',referencia);
```

Lo que tu estabas generando es:

```
update NombreTABLA set nombre = 'nombre' . 'referencia';
```

Para unir texto en MYSQL/MARIADB, debes de usar la función concat, además los nombre de los campos, no deben de llevar comillas('), estabas revolviendo código de MYSQL con el de PHP

Comment: Procura que tus respuestas vengan acompañadas de una explicaci{on, conforme a lo que dice [answer], eso asegura 2 cosas: calidad en tu aporte y que no recibas negativos