# Agrupar campos en una tabla PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en PHP y MySQL, ella muestra una tabla con registros que presentan la misma información en algunos campos,  deseo agrupar estos campos en uno solo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT productos.producto, modalidad_entrega.modalidad_entrega, tipo_producto.tipo_producto, lugar_suministro.lugar_suministro,
poliducto.poliducto, precios_jet.promedio_dolar, precios_jet.valor_transporte, precios_jet.impuesto_carbono, precios_jet.tipo_tarifa, 
precios_jet.valor_tarifa, precios_jet.transporte_adicional, precios_jet.porcentaje 
FROM precios_jet, contratos, subcontratos, lugar_suministro, poliducto, semanas, tipo_producto, modalidad_entrega, productos 
WHERE precios_jet.id_producto =productos.id_producto AND precios_jet.id_modalidad_entrega =modalidad_entrega.id_modalidad_entrega 
AND precios_jet.id_lugar_suministro =lugar_suministro.id_lugar_suministro
AND precios_jet.id_poliducto = poliducto.id_poliducto AND precios_jet.id_tipo_producto= tipo_producto.id_tipo_producto
AND precios_jet.id_contrato=contratos.id_contrato
AND precios_jet.id_subcontrato=subcontratos.id_subcontrato
AND precios_jet.id_modalidad_entrega =modalidad_entrega.id_modalidad_entrega
AND precios_jet.id_semana = semanas.id_semana
AND precios_jet.id_tipo_producto= tipo_producto.id_tipo_producto
AND precios_jet.id_contrato = '$id_contrato'
AND precios_jet.id_subcontrato='$id_subcontrato'
AND productos.producto='JET A1'
AND modalidad_entrega.modalidad_entrega = 'ALA DE AVION'
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la consulta sql que llevas al momento?

Comment: Convendría tal vez agregues como están relacionadas las tablas pues se puede mudar tu estructura al uso de joins, además del agrupamiento faltante

Comment: la consulta esta bien, lo que quiero es que al momento de imprimir en pantalla, me muestra un solo campo.

Comment: Claro sin embargo usas una sintaxis antigua desde hace ya muchos años, con join sería mas legible, por otro lado te hace falta grupar todas las columnas seleccionadas

Comment: me podrias ayudar como seria ese JOIN

Comment: No sólo es una sintaxis antigua como dice @Aprendiz , sino que haces un CROSS JOIN antes de evaluar igualdad de campos lo cual consume montón de recursos de la base de datos. Sin embargo creo que esa no es tu pregunta, si necesitas formatear el HTML ¿podrías poner el código con el que muestras tu tabla?

Answer (score 1):

En MySQL existen dos funciones para concatenar cadenas. La más conocida es `CONCAT()`, y hay otra función menos conocida que es `CONCAT_WS()`

Para agrupar varias columnas con `CONCAT()` podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT 
    productos.producto, 
    modalidad_entrega.modalidad_entrega, 
        CONCAT(
                tipo_producto.tipo_producto,' ',
                lugar_suministro.lugar_suministro,' ',
                poliducto.poliducto
              ) 
    tresCampos, 
    precios_jet.promedio_dolar, 
    precios_jet.valor_transporte, 
    precios_jet.impuesto_carbono, 
    precios_jet.tipo_tarifa, 
    precios_jet.valor_tarifa, 
    precios_jet.transporte_adicional, 
    precios_jet.porcentaje 
FROM 
    precios_jet, 
    contratos, 
    subcontratos, 
    lugar_suministro, 
    poliducto, 
    semanas, 
    tipo_producto, 
    modalidad_entrega, 
    productos 
WHERE 
    precios_jet.id_producto=productos.id_producto 
    AND precios_jet.id_modalidad_entrega=modalidad_entrega.id_modalidad_entrega;
```

**PERO**  `CONCAT()` tiene un problema: **no es amigo de los valores `NULL`**<sup>1</sup>. Significa que si en alguna concatenación alguna de las columnas es `NULL`, toda la concatenación termina resultando `NULL`.

Para estos casos `CONCAT_WS()` es una solución óptima, porque sí permite `NULL`. La sintaxis es algo distinta a `CONCAT()`, por ejemplo, si quieres el mismo separador para todas las columnas, lo pones al principio y listo.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    productos.producto, 
    modalidad_entrega.modalidad_entrega, 
        CONCAT_WS(
                    ' ',
                    tipo_producto.tipo_producto,
                    lugar_suministro.lugar_suministro,
                    poliducto.poliducto
                  ) 
    tresCampos, 
    precios_jet.promedio_dolar, 
    precios_jet.valor_transporte, 
    precios_jet.impuesto_carbono, 
    precios_jet.tipo_tarifa, 
    precios_jet.valor_tarifa, 
    precios_jet.transporte_adicional, 
    precios_jet.porcentaje 
FROM 
    precios_jet, 
    contratos, 
    subcontratos, 
    lugar_suministro, 
    poliducto, 
    semanas, 
    tipo_producto, 
    modalidad_entrega, 
    productos 
WHERE 
    precios_jet.id_producto=productos.id_producto 
    AND precios_jet.id_modalidad_entrega=modalidad_entrega.id_modalidad_entrega;
```

O, si prefieres, puedes usar `CONCAT` combinado con `COALESCE`  y/o con `IFNULL`.

Como ya comentan algunos compañeros, convendría que revises tu estilo de escribir las consultas y consideres hacer optimizaciones si fuera preciso.

---

### Notas

1. Para más detalles sobre esto consultar la pregunta: [¿Usar CONCAT o CONCAT_WS en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967). Allí hay una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86722/29967) que explica con detalle la situación.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí bien la pregunta, pero para agrupar esos tres campos podrías usar la función [CONCAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) con los 3 campos que queres agrupar