# Trigger con funcion CONCAT_WS

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Cordial saludo,
Tengo una tabla donde deseo que se guarde los `INSERT`, `UPDATE` y `DELETE` que hace el usuario que ingrese al sistema, esto para guardar una auditoria de quien hizo cualquier modificación en las tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE reg_mod (
  ID_REG timestamp NOT NULL,
  ID_USR varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  TP_OPE char(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'I - INSERT  U - UPDATE  D - DELETE',
  NB_TAB varchar(7) NOT NULL COMMENT 'NOMBRE TABLA',
  PK_COL varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'VALOR PRIMARY KEY',
  RG_ANT text,
  RG_NEW text,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_REG,ID_USR))
```

Para guardar los cambios lo hago con este procedimiento almacenado:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE REG_HIS(IN vHOR TIMESTAMP, IN vUSR VARCHAR(15), IN vOPE CHAR(1), IN vTAB VARCHAR(7),
                             IN vCLA VARCHAR(15), IN vOLD TEXT, IN vNEW TEXT)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO reg_mod (ID_REG,ID_USR,TP_OPE,NB_TAB,PK_COL,RG_ANT,RG_NEW) 
                   VALUES (vHOR,vUSR,vOPE,vTAB,vCOL,vCLA,vCLV,vOLD,vNEW);
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

En cada tabla pienso hacer un `TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE`, `BEFORE INSERT` y `BEFORE DELETE` que me guarde la información que deseo en la tabla reg_mod, como por ejemplo de una tabla llamada LISTA:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `BI_LISTA` BEFORE INSERT ON `lista`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE vUSR VARCHAR(15);
# SE UBICA EL USUARIO QUE INICIO SESION PERO SOLO SE EXTRAE EL NOMBRE QUE TENGA ANTES DEL @
  SET vUSR = LEFT(SESSION_USER(),LOCATE('@',SESSION_USER(),1) - 1);
  CALL REG_HIS(NOW(),vUSR,'I','LISTA',new.id_lis,NULL,CONCAT_WS(char(10 using utf8),CONCAT('ID_LIS = ',new.id_lis),CONCAT('DESCRI= ',new.descri));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero esto me genera el siguiente error en phpmyadmin:

```
Error
consulta SQL: Copiar


CREATE TRIGGER `BI_LISTA` BEFORE INSERT ON `lista`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE vUSR VARCHAR(15);
# SE UBICA EL USUARIO QUE INICIO SESION PERO SOLO SE EXTRAE EL NOMBRE QUE TENGA ANTES DEL @
  SET vUSR = LEFT(SESSION_USER(),LOCATE('@',SESSION_USER(),1) - 1);
  CALL REG_HIS(NOW(),vUSR,'I','LISTA',new.id_lis,NULL,CONCAT_WS(char(10 using utf8),CONCAT('ID_LIS = ',new.id_lis),CONCAT('DESCRI= ',new.descri));
END
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ';
END' en la linea 6
```

En este trigger solo estoy tratando de guardar dos campos de una tabla en `RG_NEW` por ser un `INSERT`, habrán tablas en las que hayan mas campos para guardar en `REG_MOD` y necesito que se guarde con salto de linea dos mas registros en `REG_ANT` (si es un `UPDATE` o `DELETE`) o en `REW_NEW` (si es un `INSERT` o `UPDATE`), de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es el error que me esta generando el Trigger?

Comment: Te está faltando el paréntesis de cierre aquí: `CALL REG_HIS(NOW(),vUSR,'I','LISTA',new.id_lis,NULL,CONCAT_WS(char(10 using utf8),CONCAT('ID_LIS = ',new.id_lis),CONCAT('DESCRI= ',new.descri));` agrega un paréntesis de cierre antes del `;`

Comment: Por otra parte, considera que `CONCAT` no es un *null safe*. Significa que si uno de los valores que intervienen en `CONCAT` puede ser nulo, el resultado de la concatenación no ocurrirá. [Revisa esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967) para más detalles sobre esto. Ante la posibilidad de `null` puedes resolverlo con el propio `CONCAT_WS`  o con `CONCAT` y `COALESCE` combinados.

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando el paréntesis de cierre aquí:

```
CALL REG_HIS
(
    NOW(),
    vUSR,
    'I',
    'LISTA',
    new.id_lis,
    NULL,
    CONCAT_WS
    (
        char(10 using utf8),
        CONCAT('ID_LIS = ',new.id_lis),
        CONCAT('DESCRI= ',new.descri)
    ); -- ¿Paréntesis que cierra CALL dónde está?
```

Esta es una de las ventajas de indentar el código, que puedes ver fácilmente si falta cerrar algún bloque.

Entonces, agrega el paréntesis que falta, y todo debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
CALL REG_HIS
(
    NOW(),
    vUSR,
    'I',
    'LISTA',
    new.id_lis,
    NULL,
    CONCAT_WS
    (
        char(10 using utf8),
        CONCAT('ID_LIS = ',new.id_lis),
        CONCAT('DESCRI= ',new.descri)
    )
); -- He aquí el paréntesis que faltaba
```

### Advertencia sobre los nulos

Considera que `CONCAT` no es un *null safe*. Significa que si uno de los valores que intervienen en `CONCAT` puede ser nulo, el resultado de la concatenación no ocurrirá (todo se convertirá en un valor en blanco). [Revisa esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967) para más detalles sobre esto. Ante la posibilidad de `null` puedes resolverlo con el propio `CONCAT_WS`  o con `CONCAT` y `COALESCE` combinados. De hecho, ya que usas `CONCAT_WS` aquí, puedes prescindir de los `CONCAT` haciendo esto:

```
CALL REG_HIS
(
    NOW(),
    vUSR,
    'I',
    'LISTA',
    new.id_lis,
    NULL,
    CONCAT_WS
    (
        char(10 using utf8),
        'ID_LIS = ',
        new.id_lis,
        'DESCRI= ',
        new.descri
    )
);
```

Si en agún caso el valor de `descri` es `NULL`, el resultado de la concatenación escribiendo el código así será parecido a esto:

```
---------------------
ID_LIS = 2 DESCRI=
```

En cambio, en la consulta como la tienes ahora, el `NULL` de `descri` anulará todo, obteniendo esto como resultado:

```
---------------------
                     -- Nada de nada aquí
```

Comment: Muchas gracias llevaba rato y no habia visto el error del parentesis y los campos en un INSERT ambos no pueden ser nulos, son obligatorios pero esa parte no la sabia asi que lo tendre en cuenta para un futuro.