# Valor NULL MySQL Cursores Anidados

Tags: mysql, mysql-procedimiento, mysql-cursores, mysql-cursores-anidados, mysql-8.0

Utilizando cursores anidados, mostrar para cada coche (MATRICULA, MARCA y MODELO) el nombre e importe de la pieza más cara (teniendo en cuenta el número de piezas) que se ha utilizado en una reparación, es decir, si se usan dos unidades el precio de la pieza es el doble.

```
USE TALLER;
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS import $$

CREATE PROCEDURE import()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
        DECLARE c_matricula VARCHAR(9);
        DECLARE c_marca, c_modelo VARCHAR(15);
        DECLARE c_cod_repacion VARCHAR(4);
        DECLARE c_nombre_pieza VARCHAR(12);
        DECLARE c_precio_pieza INT;
        #DECLARE c_precio_piezaMAX INT;
        DECLARE cur_coches CURSOR FOR SELECT matricula, marca, modelo FROM coches;
        DECLARE cur_reparaciones CURSOR FOR SELECT cod_repacion,nombre_pieza, precio_pieza FROM reparaciones WHERE cod_repacion=c_cod_repacion AND nombre_pieza=c_nombre_pieza;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = true;
        OPEN cur_coches;
        FETCH cur_coches INTO c_matricula, c_marca, c_modelo;
            OPEN cur_reparaciones;
            FETCH cur_reparaciones INTO c_cod_repacion, c_nombre_pieza, c_precio_pieza;
                #IF c_precio_piezaMAX > c_precio_pieza THEN
                #   SET c_precio_pieza = c_precio_piezaMAX;
                #   FETCH cur_reparaciones INTO c_nombre_pieza, c_precio_pieza;
                #END IF;
            SET fin=false;
            FETCH cur_reparaciones INTO c_cod_repacion, c_nombre_pieza, c_precio_pieza;
        SELECT CONCAT (c_matricula," ",c_marca," ", c_modelo);
        SELECT CONCAT (c_nombre_pieza," ",c_precio_pieza);
            CLOSE cur_reparaciones;
            FETCH cur_coches INTO c_matricula, c_marca, c_modelo;
        CLOSE cur_coches;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
call import();
```

Resulta que estoy intentando que me devuelva el valor del select pero en una me sale null y no se porque os dejo una imagen de lo que me devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [`CONCAT()` no es *nullsafe*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967), significa que si alguno de los valores es `NULL`, `CONCAT()` hará que todo sea `NULL` en la concatenación. Prueba así para ver lo que es `NULL` en tu resultado: **`SELECT CONCAT_WS (' ',c_nombre_pieza, c_precio_pieza);`** Si todo es `NULL` igualmente, entonces habrá que revisar más a fondo.

Comment: ¿De qué forma pretendes recorrer tus cursores? Debes usar un bucle (`LOOP`) para hacerlo, cosa que no veo en tu código. [Revisa este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/) donde te explica con claridad el modo de usar los cursores. Revisa también el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) y los códigos de ejemplo, en los cuales siempre se usa `LOOP` para vaciar los cursores.

Comment: Ummm no sé, el enunciado en tu pregunta habla de ***cada coche*** y si te pide que uses cursores, se supone que es para recorrer los valores de **cada fila**, de lo contrario, un cursor no tendría sentido aquí, como no tendría sentido un ejercicio que pretenda enseñarte a hacer algo como no se debe hacer ¿?

Comment: Es que estamos empezando yo al principio se los ejercicios se lo ponía con bucle y me dijo el profe que el no quería un bucle ya que solo pinta uno por lo que no hace falta buscar todo si no saca el primero que cumpla la condición

Comment: Si es para un solo registro no hace falta un cursor, lo obtienes con una consulta simple, sin más historia. ¿Para qué son los cursores entonces aquí?

Comment: porque estamos empezando con los cursores y no quiere que lo hagamos con consulta por ejemplo en uno de los ejercicios pedía ordenar los numero del mayor al menor y puse un order by asc y me dijo que eso era hacer trampa que tenia que haber echo if end if; porque estamos empezando y el quiere que sea simple

Comment: Pues no sé, no le veo sentido a eso. De todos modos, no sé por que haces `FETCH` dos veces a `cur_reparaciones`. Tampoco soy experto en cursores, por lo que no podría analizar con propiedad tu código.

Comment: okey no hay problema y muchas gracias de todo modos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de mucha investigacion pude resolverlo.

```
USE taller;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS importePieza$$
CREATE PROCEDURE importePieza()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
    DECLARE c1_marca VARCHAR(15);
    DECLARE c1_matricula VARCHAR(9);
    DECLARE c1_modelo VARCHAR(15);
    DECLARE c2_codRep VARCHAR(4);
    DECLARE c2_nomPieza VARCHAR(12);
    DECLARE c2_importe INT;
    DECLARE c2_unidades INT;
    DECLARE AUX INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur_coches CURSOR FOR SELECT matricula,marca,modelo FROM coches;
    DECLARE cur_piezas CURSOR FOR SELECT cod_repacion, nombre_pieza, precio_pieza,
     unidades FROM reparaciones WHERE matricula=c1_matricula;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = true;
    OPEN cur_coches;
    FETCH cur_coches INTO c1_matricula,c1_marca,c1_modelo;
    WHILE fin = false DO
        SELECT c1_matricula,c1_marca;
        OPEN cur_piezas;
         FETCH cur_piezas INTO c2_codRep, c2_nomPieza, c2_importe, c2_unidades;
        WHILE fin = false DO
            SET AUX = c2_importe*c2_unidades;
            SELECT c2_nomPieza,AUX;
            FETCH cur_piezas INTO c2_codRep, c2_nomPieza, c2_importe, c2_unidades;
        END WHILE;
        SET fin = false;
        CLOSE cur_piezas;
        FETCH cur_coches INTO c1_matricula,c1_marca,c1_modelo;
    END WHILE;
    SET fin = false;
    CLOSE cur_coches;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```