# Concatenar resultado en una variable con cursor SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, cursor

tengo un problema con un cursor en MySQL, el procedimiento tiene que leer todos los datos de email de una tabla y guardarlas en una sola variable. El caso es que me da un error de "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" y no entiendo el porque. Muchas gracias :).

El codigo del procedimiento con el cursor que tengo hecho

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE createList (
    INOUT emailList varchar(4000)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE emailAddress varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT email FROM newssupermercat;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN cursor1;
    
    bucle: LOOP
    
        SET emailList = emailList+emailAddress;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO emailAddress;
        
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE bucle;
        END IF;
        
        
        
    END LOOP bucle;

        
    CLOSE cursor1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Aqui está el codigo de la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `newssupermercat` (
  `id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Aquí estarías haciendo una operación aritmética: `SET emailList = emailList+emailAddress;` prueba a cambiarlo así: `SET emailList = CONCAT_WS(',',emailList,emailAddress);`

Comment: Tienes razón, me he dado cuenta después de que el resultado era 0 todo el rato. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo tengo, publico la respuesta y el código por si ayudo a alguien, el error de "Truncated Value" me daba al hacer el SET, se ve que da ese error si los dos tipos de variables que estás concatenando son de diferente tipo incluso con varchar de diferente longitud, la solución es o hacer un CAST o poner las variables del mismo tipo como he hecho yo.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE createList (
    INOUT emailList varchar(4000)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE emailAddress varchar(4000) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT email FROM newssupermercat;`introducir el código aquí`
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN cursor1;
    
    bucle: LOOP
        FETCH cursor1 INTO emailAddress;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE bucle;
        END IF;
        SET emailList = CONCAT(emailList,'',emailAddress,'');
    END LOOP bucle;
    CLOSE cursor1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No obstante, ten cuidado cuando uses `CONCAT`, pues si hubiera algún `NULL` hará que todo sea `NULL`. Para más detalles puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86721/29967).