# Problemas para mostrar una tabla en bootstrap y mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, bootstrap, datatables

Estoy realizando un crud con datatable y no he encontrado la forma de solucionarlo ya sea desde una cosulta en mysql o con programación en php (o alguna otra)...

Tengo tres tablas:
Polizas
Unidades(camiones)
Cajas(Remolques)

la tabla polizas tiene relacionadas las dos tablas unidades y cajas

```
SELECT id, unidades.no_unidad, cajas.numero_caja, n_poliza, tipo_unidad, cajas.capacidad, unidades.u_placas, cajas.c_placas, fe_final 
FROM polizas 
LEFT JOIN unidades 
ON polizas.id_unidad = unidades.u_id
LEFT JOIN cajas
ON polizas.id_caja = cajas.c_id
```

uso esta consulta para traer los campos que rerquiero que se muestren en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es para llamarlo a la tabla solo con las siguientes columnas

| id | economicos(no_unidad y numero caja) | numero de poliza | tipo (tipo_unidad y capacidad) | placas (u_placas y c_placas) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

así es como lo muestro con el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php 
$sentencia = $conexionBD->prepare("SELECT id, unidades.no_unidad, cajas.numero_caja, n_poliza, tipo_unidad, cajas.capacidad, unidades.u_placas, cajas.c_placas, fe_final, subir_archivo
                                                FROM polizas 
                                                LEFT JOIN unidades 
                                                ON polizas.id_unidad = unidades.u_id
                                                LEFT JOIN cajas
                                                ON polizas.id_caja = cajas.c_id"); 
$sentencia->execute(); $lista_polizas=$sentencia -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="tabla_id">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Economico</th>
                        <th scope="col">No. Póliza</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Placas</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vigencia</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estatus</th>
                        <th scope="col">Póliza PDF</th>
                        <th scope="col">Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 

                foreach ($lista_polizas as $registro) {?>

                        <tr class="">
                        <td scope="row"><?php echo $registro['id'];?></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $registro['no_unidad'];?></button></td>
                        <td><?php echo $registro['n_poliza'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $registro['tipo_unidad'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $registro['u_placas'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $registro['fe_final'];?></td>
```

como requiero que se muestre es de la siguiente forma

| id | economico | numero poliza | tipo | placa | vigencia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 239 | 3213245 | TRACTOCAMION | 98AL1U | 2024-05-01 |
| 12 | 654987 | 12345687 | CAJA 48' | BFT8596 | 2024-03-28 |

ya busqué formas, utilizo foreach en php para sacar los datos del arreglo, recurro a la comunidad por qué en realidad no se me ocurre como solucionarlo y posiblemente sea muy sencillo, pero ya estoy bloqueado, espero haber sido lo mas claro posible

gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Hola. No se entiende cuál es el problema.  ¿Es el nombre de las columnas? Usa alias. ¿Son los datos? Entonces explica qué muestra, qué debería mostrar, el código y dinos si has comprobado que los datos son correctos en tu BD.

Comment: Ok! edito para poner como es que se muestra con el códidigo que tengo

Comment: Pues sigues sin explicarnos cuál es el problema concretamente.

Comment: en la columna "Economicos" requiero mostrar el los datos de no_unidad de la tabla unidades y la numero_caja de la tabla cajas, lo mismo con la columna tipo y la clumna placas

Comment: Ah ya. Pues concatena o pon seguido el otro dato. Por ejemplo: `<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><?php printf("%s - %s",$registro['no_unidad'],$registro['numero_caja']);?></button></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente puedes poner a continuación el dato que quieras.

Dado que la mezcla de contextos PHP / HTML produce un código hiper confuso y difícil de mantener, depurar, analizar, puedes valerte de la concatenación y de **[`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php)**, para escribir un código más claro.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    $table=""; 
    
    foreach ($lista_polizas as $registro) {
        $table.='<tr class="">';
        $table.=sprintf('<td scope="row">%s</td>',$registro['id']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">%s%s</button></td>',$registro['no_unidad'],$registro['numero_caja']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['n_poliza']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s%s</td>',$registro['tipo_unidad'],$registro['capacidad']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s%s</td>',$registro['u_placas'],$registro['c_placas']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['fe_final']);
        $table.='</tr>';
    }

    // ... Cuando termines tu tabla haces un

    echo $table;
```

Si observas por ejemplo aquí:

```
$table.=sprintf('<td>%s%s</td>',$registro['tipo_unidad'],$registro['capacidad']);
```

Hemos puesto dos marcadores `%s` en la cadena, esos marcadores serán reemplazados por el valor de `$registro['tipo_unidad']` y `$registro['capacidad']` respectivamente.

Con este tipo de escritura, el código es más mantenible. Supongamos que quieres agregar otro valor, pones otro marcador y al final el nuevo valor:

```
$table.=sprintf('<td>%s%s%s</td>',$registro['tipo_unidad'],$registro['capacidad'],$registro['u_placas']);
```

O, si quieres prevenir los eventuales valores nulos, podrías hacer algo así:

```
<?php

    $table=""; 
    $economico=$registro['no_unidad'] ?? ''.$registro['numero_caja'] ?? '';
    $tipo=$registro['tipo_unidad'] ?? ''.$registro['capacidad'] ?? '';
    $placas=$registro['u_placas'] ?? ''.$registro['c_placas'] ?? '';

    foreach ($lista_polizas as $registro) {
        $table.='<tr class="">';
        $table.=sprintf('<td scope="row">%s</td>',$registro['id']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">%s</button></td>',$economico);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['n_poliza']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$tipo);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$placas);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['fe_final']);
        $table.='</tr>';
    }

    // ... Cuando termines tu tabla haces un

    echo $table;
```

---

También lo puedes resolver a nivel de SQL usando `CONCAT_WS()` que es [null safe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86722/29967). Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    CONCAT_WS('',unidades.no_unidad, cajas.numero_caja) AS economico, 
    n_poliza, 
    CONCAT_WS('',tipo_unidad, cajas.capacidad) AS tipo, 
    CONCAT_WS('',unidades.u_placas, cajas.c_placas) AS placas, 
    fe_final 
FROM polizas 
    LEFT JOIN unidades ON polizas.id_unidad = unidades.u_id
    LEFT JOIN cajas ON polizas.id_caja = cajas.c_id
```

En este caso, tendrás los valores concatenados en las columnas `economico`, `tipo` y `placas` respectivamente por lo que el código PHP quedaría de este modo.

```
<?php

    $table=""; 
    
    foreach ($lista_polizas as $registro) {
        $table.='<tr class="">';
        $table.=sprintf('<td scope="row">%s</td>',$registro['id']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">%s</button></td>',$registro['economico']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['n_poliza']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['tipo']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['placas']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td>%s</td>',$registro['fe_final']);
        $table.='</tr>';
    }

    // ... Cuando termines tu tabla haces un

    echo $table;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el día de hpy estaré implemtenado lo que me comentaste y leer mas sobre la concatenación, y estaré dando respuesta!

Comment: Listo... puse con la consulta de MySQL y funcionó correctamente!!! muchas gracias por tu ayuda, es la primera vez que consulto por aquí, voy a investigar mas sobre el tema, tendrás algun libro o alguna certificación en linéa que recomiendes para estudiar? por ahora estoy mucho más interesado en estudiar desarrollo